# Is Kingroot/Kinguser reliable for Android 4.3+?

Tags: root-access

I recently rooted an Android (Yuntab K107, Android 5.1), with Kinguser (KingRoot). So far, it has worked well (except for a hanging Busybox command), but I got this warning starting Titanium Backup:

[image: Your SU binary (version "3.75:kinguser_su") is functional but may not work reliably on some Android 4.3+ ROMs.]

Is Kinguser (KingRoot) reliable for Android 4.3+? The app (KingRoot( says it works fine for Android 5.1.1-, but Titanium Backup says it's only reliable on Android 4.2.2-.

Comment: I recommend replacing it with SuperSU for Android 5.

Comment: Most Android Enthusiasts would say that King(o)root is not reliable on any device, as it almost always installs spyware/malware. Use a proper rooting method like SuperSU or Magisk.

Comment: Apart from what was said (and I fully agree with @acejavelin here): Unless you have any issues with TiBu, you can safely ignore that warning. I do so for years, as TiBu says that for a lot of Superuser solutions. Guess SuperSU is what Joël (the author of TiBu) uses, so that's what he can check with himself.